# If a current request if AJAX one and if it's a POST one

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've googled but found nothing. How can I check in an action in a controller if a current request is an ajax one and if it's POST?

Comment: `conn.method == "POST"` and `"XMLHttpRequest" in get_req_header(conn, "x-requested-with")`?

Comment: @Dogbert, actually there's nothing related to ajax in the headers of a request, neither the header "x-requested-with" either. thus `get_req_header(conn, "x-requested-with")` returns false.

Comment: How are you making the AJAX request? Are you using jQuery or similar? Is this a cross-domain request?

Comment: @Dogbert, ajax. not cross domain. xmlhttprequest.

Answer (score 5):

For AJAX, you can check if the `x-requested-with` header's value is `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
if "XMLHttpRequest" in get_req_header(conn, "x-requested-with") do
  ...
end
```

`Plug.CSRFProtection` [does the same](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/a1b9cd2a7217fd50a714aa44e1b0e6b11f251e98/lib/plug/csrf_protection.ex#L191-L193).

For HTTP method, you can use `conn.method`:

```
if conn.method == "POST" do
  ...
end
```

Comment: as a help to others who may need this: get_req_header lives in Plug.Conn; this solution assumes an import